# JavaScript: JSLint error: wrapped in an if statement - in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Getting the error: JavaScript: JSLint error "The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype"

```
wireRecord({ data, error }) {
    var key;
    if (data) {
        this.records = data;
        if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
            for (key in data) {
                if (data[key].C1DDAPPEMP__c < 0) {
                    this.recordObj.push({
                        record: data[key],
                        isRedColor: true,
                        isYellowColor: false,
                        isGreenColor: false
                    });
                } else if (data[key].C1DDAPPEMP__c >= 0 && data[key].C1DDAPPEMP__c <= 30) {
                    this.recordObj.push({
                        record: data[key],
                        isRedColor: false,
                        isYellowColor: true,
                        isGreenColor: false
                    });
                } 

                if (data[key].SDDAPEMP__c < 0) {
                    this.recordObj.push({
                        record: data[key],
                        isRedColorSpares: true,
                        isYellowColorSpares: false,
                        isGreenColorSpares: false
                    });
                    console.log('Checking isRedColorSpares SDDAPEMP__c -----> '+data[key].SDDAPEMP__c);
                } else if (data[key].SDDAPEMP__c >= 0 && data[key].SDDAPEMP__c <= 30) {
                    this.recordObj.push({
                        record: data[key],
                        isRedColorSpares: false,
                        isYellowColorSpares: true,
                        isGreenColorSpares: false
                    });
                } 
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript: JSLint error: wrapped in an if statement - in LWC
Getting the error: JavaScript: JSLint error "The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype"

```
wireRecord({ data, error }) {
    var key;
    if (data) {
        this.records = data;
        if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
            for (key in data) {
                if (data[key].C1DDAPPEMP__c < 0) {
                    this.recordObj.push({
                        record: data[key],
                        isRedColor: true,
                        isYellowColor: false,
                        isGreenColor: false
                    });
                } else if (data[key].C1DDAPPEMP__c >= 0 && data[key].C1DDAPPEMP__c <= 30) {
                    this.recordObj.push({
                        record: data[key],
                        isRedColor: false,
                        isYellowColor: true,
                        isGreenColor: false
                    });
                } 

                if (data[key].SDDAPEMP__c < 0) {
                    this.recordObj.push({
                        record: data[key],
                        isRedColorSpares: true,
                        isYellowColorSpares: false,
                        isGreenColorSpares: false
                    });
                    console.log('Checking isRedColorSpares SDDAPEMP__c -----> '+data[key].SDDAPEMP__c);
                } else if (data[key].SDDAPEMP__c >= 0 && data[key].SDDAPEMP__c <= 30) {
                    this.recordObj.push({
                        record: data[key],
                        isRedColorSpares: false,
                        isYellowColorSpares: true,
                        isGreenColorSpares: false
                    });
                } 
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error when I add another if statement -  `if (data[key].SDDAPEMP__c < 0)`

With the first if statement I am getting the color key value in the object record appended as - this.recordObj -----> [{"record":{"Id":"a1R9H0000002Z05UAE","Name":"Q-00095","SBQQ__Opportunity2__c":"0069H000001GY1yQAG"},"isRedColor":false,"isYellowColor":false,"isGreenColor":true}]

Below is what I want to achieve when adding the second if section. I also tried placing for (key in data) { above the second if, error is gone, but the second set of spares colors not pushed/appended:

this.recordObj -----> [{"record":{"Id":"a1R9H0000002Z05UAE","Name":"Q-00095","SBQQ__Opportunity2__c":"0069H000001GY1yQAG"},"isRedColor":false,"isYellowColor":false,"isGreenColor":true,"isRedColorSpares":false,"isYellowColorSpares":false,"isGreenColorSpares":true}]

So on for a few more fields - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason behind this is the use of for in over array of records
2. To be more precise for in loop is used to loop over an object and not over an array
3. Every Object has a property called prototype which is used to extend the functionality , so that other objects of same type can use that
4. In your case since you are looping it over an array the javascript thinks that prototype is also an array element which is incorrect
5. So replace your for(keys in data with) for (var i=0;i<data.length:i++) and then you can use it as data[i]. SDDAPEMP__c and so on

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
            for (key in this.recordObj) {
                if (this.recordObj[key].record.SDDAPEMP__c < 0) {
                    this.recordObj[key].isRedColorSpares = true;
                    this.recordObj[key].isYellowColorSpares = false;
                    this.recordObj[key].isGreenColorSpares = false;
                } else if (this.recordObj[key].record.SDDAPEMP__c >= 0 && 
                    this.recordObj[key].record.SDDAPEMP__c <= 30) {
                    this.recordObj[key].isRedColorSpares = false;
                    this.recordObj[key].isYellowColorSpares = true;
                    this.recordObj[key].isGreenColorSpares = false;
                } else if (this.recordObj[key].record.SDDAPEMP__c > 30) {
                    this.recordObj[key].isRedColorSpares = false;
                    this.recordObj[key].isYellowColorSpares = false;
                    this.recordObj[key].isGreenColorSpares = true;
                }
            }
```